# I can not understand the working process of jwt and the 401 and 403 error and the work of refresh token

Tags: jwt, http-status-code-403, http-status-code-401, refresh-token

Recently I am learning jwt but I can not understand the actual work of jwt and 401 and 403 errors. It will be helpful for me if someone gives me a clear understanding of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

#### Http status 401

typically means that you are not correctly *authenticated*. This can be various things, e.g.

- you did not send JWT token in the request
- you sent JWT token in the request, but it is not valid (e.g. signature could not be validated)
- you sent JWT token in the request but it has expired.

#### Http status 403

typically means that you are not *authorized*. E.g. you provided correct JWT token, but you do not have access to the requested resource. E.g.

- a logged in user, with JWT token, tried to access an "admin page" but did not have access.